# Issue updating to database - White Screen

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to run the following script and it is just giving me a white screen even though error reporting is turned on, I have gone through the code and cant seem to find any problems with it but then I have only been using PHP for a couple of months so I am not the most experienced, many thanks in advance for your help.

The code is as follows...

```
 <?php


error_reporting(E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE);
ini_set('display_errors', TRUE);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', TRUE);


ob_start();

function isLoggedIn()
{
    if(isset($_SESSION['valid']) && $_SESSION['valid'])
        return true;
    return false;
}





session_start();
//if the user has not logged in
if(!isLoggedIn())
{
    header('Location: ../main');

    die();
}



//! Get info from POST
$cat_name = $_POST['cat_name'];
$sub_cat_name = $_POST['sub_cat_name'];
$sub_cat_link = $_POST['sub_cat_link'];
$item_name = $_POST['item_name'];
$sub_cat_link_item = $_POST['sub_cat_link_item'];
$item_price = $_POST['item_price'];
$item_desc = $_POST['item_desk'];
$item_link = $_POST['item_link'];
$ID = $_POST['ID'];

if (isset($ID)) {

//! security real escape

$cat_name = mysql_real_escape_string($cat_name);
$sub_cat_name = mysql_real_escape_string($sub_cat_name);
$item_name = mysql_real_escape_string($item_name);
$sub_cat_link = mysql_real_escape_string($sub_cat_link);
$sub_cat_link_item = mysql_real_escape_string($sub_cat_link_item);
$item_price = mysql_real_escape_string($item_price);
$item_desc = mysql_real_escape_string($item_desc);
$item_link = mysql_real_escape_string($item_link);
$ID = mysql_real_escape_string($ID);

//! Connect to the database

require_once('../Connections/PropSuite.php');
mysql_select_db($database_Takeaway, $Takeaway);

//! Write the information to the database

$query = "UPDATE menu_cats
            SET category_name = '$cat_name',
                sub_cat_name = '$sub_cat_name',
                item_name = '$item_name',
                sub_cat_id_link = '$sub_cat_link',
                sub_cat_id = '$sub_cat_link_item',
                item_price = '$item_price',
                item_desc = '$item_desc',
                item_link_id = '$item_link'

            WHERE id = $ID ;"
mysql_query($query);



    if( mysql_errno() != 0){
     // mysql error
     // note: message like this should never appear to user, should be only stored in log
     echo "Mysql error: " . htmlspecialchars( mysql_error());
     die();
}

else {

header('Location: ../main/menu-manager.php?success');

}
}

else
{
echo("An error occurred!")
}
mysql_close();

?>
```

Comment: why did u call output buffer?, and why did you close then open your php tags?

Comment: @Ibu I had an error showing up saying the headers have already been sent so I used output buffer as I have before and in the past it has worked

Comment: remove all your `?>` and you can remove the output buffer and you will be fine

Comment: A MySQL connection is required before using mysql_real_escape_string() otherwise an error of level E_WARNING is generated, and FALSE is returned. If link_identifier isn't defined, the last MySQL connection is used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
        WHERE id = $ID ;"
mysql_query($query);
```

Should be:

```
        WHERE id = $ID ";
mysql_query($query);
```

And there's a missing semicolon on:

```
echo("An error occurred!")
```

Comment: Thank you for your help :-) worked perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

You Turn on output buffering and never output the buffer.  Hence a blank page.